# How to get hierarchy of employees for a manager in mysql?

Tags: mysql, join

I have an `employee` table, with the following data.
For a particular manager, i want to get the list of all employees, following the hierarchy of the manager.

```
id  name    manager

1   John    6
2   Gill    7
3   Ben     2
4   Roy     8
5   Lenin   6
6   Nancy   7
7   Sam     0
8   Dolly   3
```

For example, i have to get the employees under manager **Sam**(7). As you can see, **Sam** does not have any manager, but he is the manager for employees **Gill** and **Nancy**, who are the managers for employees **Ben** and **John, Lenin** respectively.

So i ran a query like this:

```
select * from employee where manager=7;
```

I get the result as 2 rows, **Gill** and **Nancy**.

But now, i also want to show the employees **Ben** and **John**, **Lenin** in the output, as they both are under the managers **Gill** and **Nancy**, who are under **Sam**.

How can i structure the query to show the employees hierarchically for a manager? In other words, how can i show all **Gill**, **Nancy**, **Ben**, **John** and **Lenin** under the manager **Sam** ?

Comment: I thought of creating another table with the columns employee id and manager id, as that could ease the fetching of data. But, at this point, it is too late for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a IN subquery to your WHERE clause will handle that. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE manager = 7 OR manager IN (SELECT id FROM employee WHERE manager = 7)
```

Comment: Thanks Sean, that did it. However it works only for a single hierarchy of employees. If i have another hierarchy of employees, for example, if **Ben** is the manager for **Dolly**, as in my table above, this may not work.

Answer (score 2):

For a better visuality you can also use this query:

```
select e1.name, e2.name, e3.name 
from employee e1 
left join employee e2 on e1.id = e2.manager
left join employee e3 on e2.id = e3.manager
where e2.manager = 7
```

whereas you have to add another `left join` for each hierarchy. That is a downside on the one hand, on the other hand it's easier to handle than in Sean's answer.

On the pro side you get an output like this:

```
name        name1       name2
---------------------------------
Sam         Gill        Ben     
Sam         Nancy       John    
Sam         Nancy       Lenin
```

which is much more eye friendly and you can easily put it in an even more eye friendly form via PHP or something.